# Compact Letter Display with pairwise_wilcox_test p-values | R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is part of my dataset, in long format:

```
`dadosP7$id` `dadosP7$Atributos`                 `dadosP7$Importancia`
          <dbl> <chr>                                               <dbl>
 1            1 O Sabor                                                 4
 2            1 O Teor de gordura                                       5
 3            1 Ser isento de lactose                                   3
 4            1 Embalagem Amiga do ambiente                             4
 5            1 Marca certificada p/ BEA                                3
 6            1 Marca certificada Leite BIO                             3
 7            1 Marca certificada Leite de Pastagem                     3
 8            1 Origem Nacional                                         4
 9            1 Justiça laboral                                         4
10            1 Preço                                                   4
11            2 O Sabor                                                 1
12            2 O Teor de gordura                                       1
13            2 Ser isento de lactose                                   1
14            2 Embalagem Amiga do ambiente                             1
15            2 Marca certificada p/ BEA                                1
16            2 Marca certificada Leite BIO                             1
17            2 Marca certificada Leite de Pastagem                     1
18            2 Origem Nacional                                         1
19            2 Justiça laboral                                         3
20            2 Preço                                                   3
```

I have performed multiple pairwise comparisons using the function pairwise_wilcox_test() function, as follows:

```
library(rstatix)
wilcoxonP7 <- pairwise_wilcox_test(data = dadosP7,
formula = Importancia ~ Atributos,p.adjust.methods = "BH",
paired=TRUE,exact=TRUE)
```

Here's the heading of the pairwise_wilcox_test output :

```
.y.         group1             group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif
 * <chr>       <chr>           <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
 1 Importancia Embalagem       Justi…    65    65     168.  1.7 e-1 1   e+0 ns          
 2 Importancia Embalagem       Marca…    65    65     600   4.9 e-2 8.3 e-1 ns
```

I have also plotted the means of the "Importancia" variable for each group, using:

```
ggplot(dadosP7, aes(x = reorder(Atributos, Importancia), y = Importancia)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar",aes(fill="paleturquoise3")) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), vjust = -0.5, aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", ..y..)), vjust=-0.5,hjust=-0.6,size = 5) +
  ylim(0, 5) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Atributos")+
  coord_flip()
```

Here is the plot that I obtained:
[image]

How can I add letters at the top of the bars (label mean values can be removed if needed) that show which differences are significant, based on values of `p.adj`?

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out how to plot the letters automatically. But I can plot them manually using this code:

```
theme(text = element_text(size=16),axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size=.5, lineend="round"), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size=.5, lineend="round"))+
  annotate("text", x = 0.78, y = 0.35, label = "a", size = 5) + #1
  annotate("text", x = 1.78, y = 0.48, label = "a", size = 5) + #3
  annotate("text", x = 2.22, y = 0.27, label = "a", size = 5) + #4
  annotate("text", x = 1.215, y = 0.48, label = "a", size = 5)+ #2
```

You just need to adapt to your situation.

I hope this helps you!